# parallel processing loops using completable future

Tags: java, completable-future

There is a list of locations and requests passed as an input by the user. For each location, requests have to be processed asyncrhonously and create an offer for each request. I tried to implement the task using completable future but its not creating offers for all requests. What am I missing?

```
    List<CompletableFuture<List<Offer>>> allLocationOffers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Location location : locations) {
                    CompletableFuture<List<Offer>> locationOffersFuture = processRequestsForLocation(locationRequestsList);
                    allLocationOffers.add(locationOffersFuture);
        }
    
     List<Offer> allOffers = new ArrayList<>();
    
            for (CompletableFuture<List<Offer>> locationOffersFuture : allLocationOffers) {
                try {
                    List<Offer> locationOffers = locationOffersFuture.get();
                    allOffers.addAll(locationOffers);
                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    
    public static CompletableFuture<List<Offer>> processRequestsForLocation(List<Request> locationRequests) {
            return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                List<Offer> offers = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Request request : locationRequests) {
                   //create offer and add to offers
                    offers.add(offer);
                }
                return offers;
            }, Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
        }
```

Comment: I would definitely pull that `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` into its own `static` variable, rather than remaking new thread pools for every invocation. Can you clarify what you mean by "doesn't make offers"? E.g. empty lists, incomplete futures, and so on. The question needs debugging details.

Comment: @Rogue ,  the number of total offers created should be equal to the requests. But the results is inconsistent, sometimes doesnt create offers at all sometimes 1 less than the actual number.

Comment: There’s not enough code here to reproduce or debug the problem. My first suspicion would be that something is throwing an exception. I don’t see any way that the code provided here could create a different number of offers than the number of location requests. It also isn’t clear why it uses `CompletableFuture` at all, so my guess is that there’s something important in the code that was left out. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: 1. How do you determine the number of requests you are comparing to the number of offers? 2. Your first loop iterates over `locations` without using the elements. Instead, it passes the same `locationRequestsList` to the method in each operation. This is unlikely to be your actual intended application logic. 3. You are catching exceptions and proceeding afterwards. Calling `printStackTrace()` is not a sufficient exception handling, as we do not know where this will be printed to or whether anyone will ever read it. Maybe, elements are missing because there were some exceptions…